# Crystal Report - Label Printing with a varied page counter

Tags: crystal-reports

So, our branches are wanting shipping labels created which I have created a template on Crystal reports.
Our issue is using the NofM function. If the user prints one label it will say 1of1 which is correct. We want it so the counter is determined by the number of prints they require for example:

If the user prints 4 pages it will be 1of4 to 4of4.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In Field Explorer, expand '***Special Fields***'.

Use the '***Page N of M***' special field.

Comment: That would work if it was a continuous document but I want it to be a user input method for example, the user opens our smart view they get a prompt for the Order NO. and how many labels, I then want the Label that print to take the variable passed and put it into the 1 of X

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a solution to duplicate the printing copies based on a parameter.

Option 1. if the max expected quantity is not too large, you can create multiple sections (Details a, Details b, Details c, ...) and use a dynamic suppress condition to hide the sections beyond the quantity parameter.

Option 2. Create a "REPEATER" table with a single column (How_Many) and rows for 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ...

Now, in your report, add the REPEATER Table and add a Record Selection condition of

```
{?QTY} >= {Repeater.How_Many}
```

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. Basically just print multiple labels based on user input while having 1 of X.
Quick one though, I am basically VERY new to crystal how do I set up a repeater table

Comment: You create it in the database.